# Not being able to change CSS through jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i have one div whose **css has display none set**

```
.cookie_policy
{
color: white;
text-align: justify;
width: 50%;
margin: 2% 25%;
line-height: 20px;
display: block;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
display:none;
}
<div class="cookie_policy">
    my html here
</div>
```

when dropdown change then i am trying to show the div if the drodown value is GB

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
                if (this.value.indexOf('gb') != -1) {
                    //$('#cookie_policy').show();
                    $("#cookie_policy").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                }
                else {
                    $("#cookie_policy").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                }
                return false;
            });
```

but i do not know where i made the mistake in code as a result div is not showing. i use firebug to see the css value then i saw still css has `none` property. i use jquery `show()` but still div is not getting visible.

i am using jquery version `jquery-1.4.1.min.js`

please guide me where i am making the mistake

Comment: Doing some basic debugging would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector; use `.` instead of `#` since you want to style a class:

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
    if (this.value.indexOf('gb') != -1) {
        //$('#cookie_policy').show();
        $(".cookie_policy").css({ 'display': 'block' });
    } else {
        $(".cookie_policy").css({ 'display': 'none' });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#cookie_policy")` is a selector for an id, you need a class judging by your css `$(".cookie_policy")`

e.g.

```
var $cookiePolicy = $('.cookie_policy');

$('#ddlCountry').change(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $cookiePolicy[this.value === 'gb' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

1. Use === and !== (double equals) so that you code with type-awareness
2. Don't return false unless you wanted to stop propagation, which I don't think you did (use preventDefault)
3. Cache the cookie_policy selector
4. Use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it is more succinct and descriptive
5. Don't use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) unless there was something after 'gb' - if there was then fair enough.